# "Try and Guess" Is Not Enough

Tags: riddle, word

Don't be fooled by the easy appearance of this riddle. The answer gets you to first base but to get a gold star, you must find and explain *all* of the clues. It took a good deal of effort to compose this so I intend to make you work to get the answer. If you find twelve or fewer, try it again. My advice would be to take it in stages.

> Trailing and getting a man at a bag
>   At the end of a tail it's an earmark or flag.
>   Giving a touch, give it a name
>   Greatest in code but it's kind of a game
>   A part of a lace maybe something you spray
>   Take a gathering back in advantage I say.

Rate yourself:
(Spoilers ahead!)

> How many clues did you find, excluding this section?
>     0 - 11    Low wattage performance
>     12 - 16   Staggering to the finish line
>     17 - 21     Join the montage of champions!
>     22 and up   The "taggant agita greeting" award

Comment: you have created a nice game for me.. :)

Comment: @manshu You can be like a secret agent hunting spies.

Comment: Don't you know that [I already am](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/52388522.jpg)

Comment: Sheesh. That's so many things to squeeze into such a small puzzle. This is fun!!!

Comment: Not a trifling matter. And then there are the comments.

Comment: Wow! What a riddle! You really did work hard on that!

Comment: Opportunity missed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrochordon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it:

> tag

Trailing and getting a man at a bag

> Trailing And Getting (TAG) 
>  tagging someone out at a base 
>  aT A baG

At the end of a tail it's an earmark or flag.

> Tagging of animals

Giving a touch, give it a name

> tagging someone
>  Giving A Touch (TAG)
>  givinG A Touch

Greatest in code but it's kind of a game

> Coding tags
>  Tag is a game

A part of a lace maybe something you spray

> parts of lace are called tags 
>  Tag body spray
>  Tagging via graffiti

Take a gathering back in advantage I say.

> Take A Gathering (TAG) 
>  Back referencing tag backwards in GAThering
>  AdvanTAGe

also

> TAG appears as the first letters to series of words a few times in the pre-text to the poem/riddle. As well as in the title... "Try And Guess"

But wait. There's more.

> The first letter of each line reads TAGGAT
>  "try iT AGain" and "take it in sTAGes" 
>  
>  Man at a baG AT the 
>  The Answer Gets 
>  Took A Good

Wouldn't surprise me if there's more. That's far more than twelve though. ;)

> Do I geT A Gold star? Or at least do I geT A Green checkmark?

Comment: Another: The Answer Gets

Comment: Already covered that. There's a few in the opening para. @manshu

Comment: last letters of "at a bag"

Comment: I will accept body spray although I was thinking graffiti.

Comment: :). So many!!! Hahahaha.

Comment: Added. Yah. Both work.

Comment: Another: GAThering

Comment: @manshu Indeed. With "back" to point a reversing direction.

Comment: @HughMeyers I never saw this hint...WOW...you really have put a lot of efforts in this puzzle...

Comment: Tell you what. Find three more in the body of the poem and the tick is yours. For the lace clue, you meant aglet, right?

Comment: Another: givinG A Touch

Comment: Another: meanT AGlet.....(OP in one of his comments)

Comment: Another: noT A triflinG matter..(OP in one of his comments)

Comment: Another: secreT AGent ...(OP in one of his comments)

Comment: Haha. His comments were chosen carefully. But I added a few more.

Comment: Disappointed there's no mention of skin tags.

Comment: Hahahaha. Cuz that'd just be weird. @RossPresser

Answer (score 6):

Though a green tick was awarded, I was never one to let a good thing go to waste. Therefore, please accept the short addenda following:

Trailing and getting a man at a bag

> Trailing is "tagging along"

At the end of a tail it's an earmark or flag.

> The colored bit at the end of an animal's tail is a tag. Earmarking and flagging are synonyms for tagging

Greatest in code

> HTML and other tags are in angle brackets which look like "greater than" and "less than" sign making the tag look greater than its surroundings.

Giving a touch, give it a name

> Tag can also be nickname

So,

> Thanks and goodbye is the message I send.
>  In this couplet that comes as a tag at the end.

Comment: **T**hanks **A**nd **G**oodbye to a great puzzle - you're it! :) )

Comment: @PaulEvans "**T**o **A** **G**reat puzzle" you mean? **T**hat's **A** **G**ood example of coincidence

Comment: @manshu Thought about going there and god save me I did!

Comment: I was happy I got a tag reference in every sentence in the in the intro here.

Comment: @PaulEvans Trying a game to a greater player? Get a Team.

Comment: @manshu I'm no competition. I left that arena going "I've met a giant!"

Comment: That's a gibber. Giants are the things a guy cannot meet.

Comment: @manshu You're way too tough and got me in a stagger!

Comment: @PaulEvans That's a gibber too. You two are good. But I have got amazing thoughts to a greater good.